# Hover father div > show child div. OnMouseOut > hide child div after X seconds

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to show the `<span>` when mouseover the `<div>` and after 5 seconds hide the `<span>`. Can't get this to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
  var timeout;
  $('.ShowCat').on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $('#' + altDiv).show();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  });
  $('.ShowCat').on("mouseout", function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + altDiv).hide();
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div alt="REF-C000000" class="ShowCat">C000000</div>
<span id="REF-C000000" class="hide">C1 C2 C3</span>
<br>
<div alt="REF-C000001" class="ShowCat">C000001</div>
<span id="REF-C000001" class="hide">C4 C5 C6</span>
```

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Your title mentions _"father div > show child div"_ but you don't have any child/parent relationships in your markup, they're all siblings. Is this markup required? Why not actually nest the `<span>` inside the `<div>`?

Comment: It will work like a dropdrown menu. There is no more reference needed. Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys check my answer it associates a timeout for each ShowCat element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reference the ID of the `<span>` in the `<div>` if the markup is always going to be a `<div>` followed by a `<span>`. Use jQuery [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get the immediate next sibling element.

```js
var $show = $( '.ShowCat' );

$show.on( 'mouseover', function ( e ) {
  
    var $this = $( this );
        
    clearTimeout( $this.data( 'tID' ) );
        
    $this.next().show();
    
} );
  
  
$show.on( 'mouseout', function ( e ) {
  
    var $this = $( this );
    
    $this.data( 'tID', setTimeout( function () {
      $this.next().hide();  
    }, 5000 ) );
    
} );
```

```css
.hide {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ShowCat">C000000</div>
<span id="REF-C000000" class="hide">C1 C2 C3</span>
<br>
<div class="ShowCat">C000001</div>
<span id="REF-C000001" class="hide">C4 C5 C6</span>
```

With my solution I'm assuming you always want the `<span>` to hide five seconds after they `mouseout` the `<div>`. To do this I had to re-work how `setTimeout()` was being handled. Your original code was canceling the five second `setTimeout()` whenever another `.ShowCat` was hovered, effectively leaving it visible.

#### Example of Original Side Effect

```js
var $show = $( '.ShowCat' ),
    tID;

$show.on( 'mouseover', function ( e ) {
  
    var $this = $( this );
        
    clearTimeout( tID );
        
    $this.next().show();
    
} );
  
  
$show.on( 'mouseout', function ( e ) {
  
    var $this = $( this );
    
    tID = setTimeout( function () {
      $this.next().hide();  
    }, 5000 );
    
} );
```

```css
.hide {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ShowCat">C000000</div>
<span id="REF-C000000" class="hide">C1 C2 C3</span>
<br>
<div class="ShowCat">C000001</div>
<span id="REF-C000001" class="hide">C4 C5 C6</span>
```

Hover the first `<div>` then hover the second `<div>` without re-hovering the first `<div>`, first `<span>` stays red while second `<span>` disappears.

If you do need to reference the `<span>` ID on the `<div>` I'd recommend using a [`data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) as `alt` is not a valid attribute for a `<div>`. `alt` is valid for the following elements: `<applet>`, `<area>`, `<img>`, `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

your code does work, you are assigning the value of `altDiv` in the wrong place...

change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        let altDiv = ""
        var timeout;
    $('.ShowCat').on("mouseover", function(e) {
        altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
        //console.log(altDiv);
        $('#' + altDiv).show();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
    $('.ShowCat').on("mouseout", function() {
         timeout = setTimeout(function() { $('#' + altDiv).hide(); }, 5000);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
```

is not doing what you think. `this` points to the parent function scope, in this case, the function that `.ready` is calling; it is not referencing the element that you are hovering. Instead, you should capture the value of the alt attribute within your handler:

```
$('.ShowCat').on("mouseover", function(e) {
  var altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
  $('#' + altDiv).show();
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

**Note** `alt` attribute on the div element is invalid, so I'd recommend instead using `data-alt="..."` and getting it with `.data` instead:

```
var altDiv = $(this).data('alt');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution a timeout is associated to each ShowCat element, not sure if this applies to your requirements:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ShowCat').on("mouseover", function(e) {
  var timeout = $(this).data('timeout');
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#' + altDiv).show();
    });
    $('.ShowCat').on("mouseout", function() {
        var altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() { $('#' + altDiv).hide(); }, 5000);
        $(this).data('timeout', timeout);
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  background-color: red;  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div alt="REF-C000000" class="ShowCat">C000000</div>
<span id="REF-C000000" class="hide">C1 C2 C3</span>
<br>
<div alt="REF-C000001" class="ShowCat">C000001</div>
<span id="REF-C000001" class="hide">C4 C5 C6</span>
```